# Add items to a .net combo and not fire selection changed?

Tags: .net, combobox

I have comboboxes with lists of files in them. These periodically change due to user input, and I need the lists to update. However, I also have selection-changed actions, and when I update the list, those fire. This has bad side-effects I'd like to get rid of.

Yes, I know I can set a bool somewhere and set/reset it, but is there really no way to do this with the combobox itself? Is there no way to change the list without firing the event?

Here is my current setup code:

```
    Dim XLL As New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of String)
    Dim XLS As New BindingSource
    XLS.DataSource = XLL
    ComboBox3.DataSource = XLS
```

Here's where I periodically update the list:

```
    Dim allFiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles(appPath, "*.xlsx")
    XLFiles.Clear()
    For Each F As String In allFiles
        XLFiles.Add(Path.GetFileName(F))
    Next F
    ComboBox3.DataSource = Nothing
    ComboBox3.DataSource = XLFiles
```

I notice that if you don't set it to Nothing, the list doesn't update. But if you do set it to Nothing, selection fires.

Am I missing some simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disconnect your selection changed handler before the update and reconnect it after.  If there is a value currently selected , you will need to save and restore that also.

```
SaveSelection();

myCombo.SelectedIndexChanged -= fooSelectionChanged;

// do list updates

ResetSelection();
myCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += fooSelectionChanged;
```

SelectedValueChanged would be handled similarly

Comment: Ahh, this is simpler. Still it seems surprisingly complex.